# Sound player that will load multiple tracks but won't play each sequentially?

Tags: software-recommendation, multimedia, video-player, music-player

I'm looking for a sound or video player that will:

- play one (and only one) of a set of tracks on demand,
- play a track with minimal interaction (ideally a single click), and
- either load multiple tracks into memory, or somehow load tracks from disk without much of a pause.

I've tried a handful of movie/music players, and they all see to want to play through an entire playlist rather than just a single track.  Re-loading each track when it's required is both a hassle and doesn't have the response time I'm looking for, perhaps because I'm using a Netbook.

Is there a player out there that might work better for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Quodlibet. There's a "One track" play order that will play one track then stop.

Comment: The play button exhibits some strange behavior, but double-clicking the track does indeed just play one song and stop.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by strange. It's a play/pause button. 1: play 2: pause 3: play etc ...

Comment: If I hit the play button after having played the last track, Quod plays the first track.  If I hit the play button after playing any other track, it plays the same track again.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Banshee](http://packages.ubuntu.com/banshee)[image: Install banshee]: Play a song, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or select `Playback` → `Stop When Finished` - it will do so.

[image: stop when finished menu]

This setting will be memorized for one song only, which means you have to activate this each time you play a song. For this issue a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/987682) exists.

Comment: It appears that the "Stop When Finished" feature only takes effect for a single press of the play button.  In other words, if I enable "Stop When Finished" and hit play, the player stops after one song as expected.  If I hit play again immediately, however, it plays through the entire list without stopping.

Comment: You are right. When I checked it yesterday I pressed "next" or chose another song by double-clicking it. Then it works. But this doesn't help in your case. You can take a look here for other audio players: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/AudioPlayer - it's in German, but it could be helpful, though, I think.

Comment: Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/987682

Comment: Bug was denied.  Supposedly it's as designed, though I think the rationale is pretty silly.  I added my thoughts too, fwiw.  Thanks for the effort!